# Using Inner Join & Distinct in one query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables (shown below) called Merge_Codes & Factors. I am trying to write a query that takes the distinct countries from the factors table and joins this to the Merge_Codes table and returns the region.

Please see the results table at the bottom to see what I mean. I am trying to do this in one query but am getting no where near the solution, as you can see from the sql below.

```
SELECT * FROM Merge_Codes
INNER JOIN ON
(SELECT DISTINCT Country FROM Factors)
```

Merge_Codes Table

```
Region     Country 
EU         Germany
EU         France
EU         Italy
Asia       Japan
Asia       Hong Kong
NA         Canada
NA         USA
SA         Brazil
SA         Peru
SA         Chile
```

Factors Table

```
Factor     Country 
ABC        Germany      
ABC        Germany      
ABC        Japan        
ABC        USA          
ABC        USA          
ABC        Hong Kong
```

Result

```
Country    Region
Germany    EU
Japan      Asia
USA        NA
Hong Kong  Asia
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select mc.*
from Merge_Codes mc
join (select distinct Country FROM Factors) f
  on mc.Country = f.Country
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select
    MC.Country,
    MC.Region
from 
    (SELECT DISTINCT Country FROM Factors) DC
    INNER JOIN Merge_Codes MC ON MC.Country = DC.Country
```